Does quasi-symmetry preserve the solution of the equation of motion?
In some field theory textbooks, such as the CFT Yellow Book (P40), the authors claim that a theory has a certain symmetry, which means that the action of the theory does not change under the symmetry transformation. For example, given a theory $\mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial\phi)$ living in a $d$-dimensional flat space, if the following coordinates mapping and the associated field transformation
$$
x\to x'=f_w(x),\quad\phi(x)\to\phi'(x')=F_w[\phi(x)]\tag{1}
$$
form a symmetry transformation, where the subscript $w$ parameterizes the symmetry, then we have
\begin{align}
S_{V'}[\phi']\equiv\int_{V'}d^dx'\mathcal{L}(\phi',\partial'\phi')=S_{V}[\phi]\equiv\int_{V}d^dx\mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial\phi),\tag{2}
\end{align}
where $V'$ is the image of $V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ under the mapping $f_w$. We can obtain the following reasonable conclusion from (2):

Conclusion 1. if the field configuration $\phi^{\star}$ is on-shell, i.e., $\phi^\star$ satisfies the equation of motion (EoM), then $F_w[\phi^\star]$ is also on-shell.


proof . since $S_V[\phi^\star+\delta\phi]$ (where $\delta\phi|_{\partial V}=0$) gets its minimum at $\delta\phi=0$, then using eq.(2) we know that $S_{V'}[F_w[\phi^\star+\delta\phi]]=S_{V'}[F_w[\phi^\star]+\delta\phi']$ (where we  have $\delta\phi'|_{\partial V'}=0$) gets its minimum at $\delta\phi'=0$. Therefore $\phi'$ is on-shell $\square$.

However, in some other textbooks, such as in Peskin's QFT book (P17) and Banados et al's review of Noether's theorem (P17), I found that the definition of symmetry is more relaxed. The action before and after the symmetry transformation (1), in their statements, can be up to a surface term, that is, we have
$$
S_{V'}[\phi']=S_{V}[\phi]+\int_{\partial V}dS_{\mu}K^\mu(\phi,\partial\phi). \tag{3}
$$
However, once $K^{\mu}$ is allowed to be a function of $\partial\phi$, I cannot reproduce conclusion 1. The reason is that when I imitated the proof above, I found that
$$
\int_{\partial V}dS_{\mu}K^\mu(\phi^\star+\delta\phi,\partial\phi^\star+\partial\delta\phi)
$$
is not $\delta\phi$-independent. Because we only imposed the condition of $\delta\phi=0$ on the boundary $\partial V$, but not the condition $\delta\partial\phi|_{\partial V}=0$. Therefore in this case I can't prove that $S_{V'}[F_w[\phi^\star]+\delta\phi']$ gets its minimum at $\delta\phi'=0$.
Here is my question: Can we reproduce conclusion 1 in the relaxed symmetry definition (3) without adding more conditions like $\delta\partial\phi|_{\partial V}=0$?
Note added: I found a very similar Post in Phys.SE "Invariance of action $\Rightarrow$ covariance of field equations?" In that question, @Qmechanic called this relaxed symmetry definition (3) quasi-symmetry and gave a positive answer. However, as he said, he dropped the boundary contribution in the derivation, thus making the proof less rigorous.

Boundary condition is a part of the very definition of your field theory, classical or quantum.  When e.g Peskin & Shroeder leaves out the surface term, "all fields and derivatives vanish at infinity" is implicit in the definition and cannot be messed with.  Relaxing the condition, and you are talking about a different model altogether.
Classically, the surface term does not change the Euler-Lagrange equation of motion, but if it doesn't vanish, the "transformation" is still not a symmetry.  Let's consider the following example.
Let's have an elastic string in weightless 2D space, both ends fixed at some points.  The distance between end points is bigger than the string's natural length, so the string is always taut.  Assume Newtonian physics.  The action follows from the quadratic $mv^2/2$ kinetic energy and a potential energy that is also quadratic in local deformation along the string.  In particular, the equation of motion should be local.
It appears that a rigid translation of the entire string preserves action and therefor the local equation of motion, but it breaks the fixed boundary condition. It induces infinite strain at the fixed end points, and the associated boundary term is badly divergent.  Rigid translation is not a symmetry.  The same logic stands even if you manage to cook up an example where the boundary term is finite.  It is not a symmetry if the surface term is not strictly zero.
A quantum system is instead defined by the partition function $Z = \int \exp(iS)$, so we have a more exotic possibility: the transformed action can change by some multiple of $2\pi$ and still be identified with the original one!  Usually this affects theories defined on a compact manifold.  The equation of motion is invariant, but the quantum spectrum is altered.
If you want to read more about this, a good place to start is the topological $\theta$ term of the quantized $U(1)$ gauge theory.

Thank you very much for your response! According to the first paragraph of your answer, does it mean that the surface term in (3) should always be zero provided I put $\partial V$ to infinity? But how should I set my boundary conditions if $V$ is a finite region?

As I said, boundary condition is part of the definition.  So it is up to you to decide what boundary condition is appropriate for the system you are describing.

Thank you for your explanation. For classical mechanics, I think I understand what you mean. But for the quantum case, I still don't quite understand why boundary conditions are important. In the path integral, in addition to the on-shell fields, we also need to pay attention to the contributions of the off-shell fields. Do these off-shell fields also have to satisfy the same boundary conditions? If so, why?

@Hezaraki From the path integral quantization point of view, boundary condition defines the support of the functional measure.  There is no field configuration that breaks boundary conditions, as much as there is no configuration such that e.g. a scalar $\phi$ can take a vector value.

Sorry, what do you mean by "boundary condition defines the support of the functional measure"? For example, for the path integral of a free scalar $\int [d\phi]\exp{i\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} d^dx(\partial\phi)^2}$, Why should I impose the condition that $\phi$ and it derivatives vanish at infinity?

"Support of functional measure" is a more rigorous way to say "domain of functional integration".  That condition is usually chosen for the simple reason that the action must exist in the first place.  It is just as fundamental as the choice of $(\partial\phi)^2$ Lagrangian density.
